# I think emoji are killing my WordPress site… How can I debug?

Tags: php, theme-development

I have had a rather frustrating last couple of days… after quite a bit of trial and error, I have come to the suspicion that emoji are killing my WordPress installation. Specifically, emoji in the settings of my theme.

[image: Screenshot]

In retrospect, I can see that even trying to use emoji was a bit of a risky proposition. As I understand it, they are not officially a part of the UTF-8 character set.

For the time being, I have tried to carefully go back through all of my theme settings and eliminate any use of emoji anywhere. But now, I would like to find out exactly how they are breaking WordPress and where. Trouble is, I'm not familiar with PHP beyond the basics I've needed to pick up for theme customization.

Where should I begin to debug this problem?

Comment: Do you have error messages? Have you active the `WP_DEBUG` constant`?

Comment: I don't even know where to look for error messages from PHP. I'm using the Bitnami stack for Mac on my desktop to try and diagnose… There is nothing obvious (to me) in the Apache logs. I didn't find the MySQL logs in my quick, 5m hunt so far.

Comment: Open your config file and enable WP_DEBUG, see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress When let us know if you see any errors...

Comment: if you enable [Debugging in your `wp_config.php` file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) then browse your website, it there are errors you can choose to display them to the screen or add them to a `debug.log` file in your `wp-content` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of MySQL’s UTF-8 implementation: it supports just a limited set of valid UTF-8 characters. You can convert your database to `utf8mb4`, and emojis will work. But there may be other side effects.

See [ticket #21212](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21212) for details.

Comment: How do you know it isn't "killing the site" with slow initialization of editors? There is a bug on this that is especially bad when there are multiple editors, and there is around half second lag when Chrome parses the regex. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32197